# Expresso Store, email address for auto generated emails

Tags: expresso-store, email

I'm using Expresso Store, everything is working fine, except the final email generated at the end of the process has an incorrect reply to address.  When the customer replies to an email, their reply is not going to the correct client address, but an old, no longer used one.  Can anyone tell me where expresso store pulls it's email addresses from?

I've put the new address in the BCC field in email settings and in Admin > Email Configuration > Return email address for auto-generated emails is this correct?

On a related note, does anyone know where I can check the email address that the admin email is sent to?  Can't seem to find it anywhere.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to make sure that you have changed both the **Admin > Email Configuration > Return email address for auto-generated emails** as you have already done, also you will want to change Store > Settings > General > Store Email Sender Address to be the new email address. Once you have done that it should be sending from the new email address.

The email templates that an admin receives are set up on a per email basis. You would need to go to **Store > Settings > Email Templates > then click on each of the templates you would like the admin to receive** and make sure that you have added their email address to the BBC field and save the template.